# Return a string literal from a function

Tags: c

I need a function to return a string depending on a code value and a secondary value, I think the sample code shows what I intend to do and probably there is a simple way to do this but I'm stuck. There will be many code numbers and this is the best way I could think of doing it in C but I get a compilation error because apparently I can't do a declaration inside a case. I'd appreciate any help correcting this.

```
char *response(int code, int alt) {
    switch ((int)code)
    {
        case 1:
            char *key[] = {"msg1","msg1_alt"};
        case 2:
            char *key[] = {"msg2","msg2_alt"};
        default:
            return "unknown";
    }
    return key[alt];
}
```

[update from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62845338/return-a-string-literal-from-a-function#comment111134732_62845338):]

In the sample if the value of the code variable is 1 and the value of alt is 0 I want the function to return "msg1" y code == 2 and alt==0 the function should return "msg2" and if code == 2 and alt==1 the function should return "msg2_alt" and so on. So the values of alt will always be 0 or 1, and if the code is not recognized the return string is "unknown"-

Comment: Can you explain, in plain english, what you want to return for code 1 and 2? and what you want to return otherwise?

Comment: Just a string depending in the code number and the alt value, in the sample if the value of the code variable is 1 and the value of alt is 0 I want the function to return "msg1" y code == 2 and alt==0 the function should return "msg2" and if code == 2 and alt==1 the function should return "msg2_alt" and so on. So the values of alt will always be 0 or 1, and if the code is not recognized the return string is "unknown"

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) then some [C language reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Comment: You can do, e.g. `case 1: { char *key[] = {"msg1","msg1_alt"}; return key[alt]; }` The wrapping in `{...}` is required to create a block to declare `char *key[]` in. A `switch()` statement is not a separate scope.  And you would have to return from WITHIN the `{ ... }` to prevent `key` from going out of scope prior to return. Also note you should return `const char *` as you are returning a pointer to a *String Literal*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about simply this:

```
char *response(int code, int alt) {
  char *(msgs)[2];

  switch (code)
  {
    case 1:
    {
      msgs[0] = "msg1";
      msgs[1] = "msg1_alt";
      break;
    }

    case 42:
    {
      msgs[0] = "msg42";
      msgs[1] = "msg42_alt";
      break;
    }

    default:
      msgs[0] = "unknown";
      msgs[1] = "unknown_alt";
      break;
  }

  return msgs[alt];
}
```

If you for what ever reasons prefer the pattern `{"...", "..."}` you could do:

```
char *response(int code, int alt) {
  char *(msgs)[2];

  switch (code)
  {
    case 1:
    {
      memcpy(msgs,  (char*[2]){"msg1", "msg1_alt"}, sizeof msgs);
      break;
    }

    case 42:
    {
      memcpy(msgs,  (char*[2]){"msg42", "msg42_alt"}, sizeof msgs);
      break;
    }

    default:
      memcpy(msgs,  (char*[2]){"unknown", "unknown_alt"}, sizeof msgs);
      break;
  }

  return msgs[alt];
}
```

If for the latter version you dislike the call to `memcpy()` you could wrap the array into a `struct` which allowed you to use the `=`-operator instead:

```
char *response(int code, int alt) {
  struct Msgs {
    char *(msgs)[2];
  } msgs_s;

  switch (code)
  {
    case 1:
    {
      msgs_s = (struct Msgs){{"msg1", "msg1_alt"}};
      break;
    }

    case 42:
    {
      msgs_s = (struct Msgs){{"msg42", "msg42_alt"}};
      break;
    }

    default:
      msgs_s = (struct Msgs){{"unknown", "unknown_alt"}};
      break;
  }

  return msgs_s.msgs[alt];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
char *response(int code, int alt) {
    char *key[ ] = {"msg1", "msg1_alt", "msg2", "msg2_alt"};
    switch (code) {
        case 1: return key[alt];
        break;
        case 2: return key[alt+2];
        break;
        default: return "unknown";
    }
}
```

Comment: what would happen if `alt` is 32767 ? Read more about [undefined behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)

Comment: As far as I understand from the question, the value of alt will be either 0 or 1, and I hope that will be maintained properly in the caller function

Comment: Thanks for the suggstion but this would be messy because I'm going to need a lot of code messages and their alternative message. Also if later I need to change one message depending on the code number it'd be a pain to find with message belonging to which code.

Comment: Hey Daniel, if you find my answer useful, please don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the **Tick mark** and also give an upvote. If you have any problem with the answer, let me know in the comments. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it using a 2D array.

Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *response(int code, int alt) {
    static char *key[][2] = { {"msg1","msg1_alt"}, {"msg2","msg2_alt"} };
 
    if (code < 1 || code > 2 || alt < 0 || alt > 1) return "unknown";
 
    return key[code-1][alt];
}
 
int main(void) {
    char *msg;

    msg = response(1,0);
    printf("%s\n", msg); 

    msg = response(2,1);
    printf("%s\n", msg); 

    msg = response(42,-5);
    printf("%s\n", msg); 

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
msg1
msg2_alt
unknown
```

You can improve the code by not hard coding the upper limit of `code`.

Change:

```
if (code < 1 || code > 2 || alt < 0 || alt > 1) return "unknown";
```

into

```
if (code < 1 || 
    code > (sizeof key / sizeof key[0][0] / 2) ||  // Calculate limit based on array
    alt < 0 || 
    alt > 1) return "unknown";
```

Then all you need to do when adding more code values, is to add them to the stitic array.

For instance:

```
static char *key[][2] = { {"msg1","msg1_alt"}, 
                          {"msg2","msg2_alt"},
                          {"msg3","msg3_alt"},
                          {"msg4","msg4_alt"},
                          {"msg5","msg5_alt"} };
```

No other code change is needed.

Comment: This would be great except it can't know if the code is known or not, aka there is not "unknown" return message

Comment: @Daniel Just return "unknown" instead of NULL. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create block scopes within each `case` by enclosing the case in `{ ... }`, for example, you can do:

```
const char *response(int code, int alt) {
    switch (code)
    {
        case 1: {
            char *key[] = {"msg1","msg1_alt"};
            return key[alt];
        }
        case 2: {
            char *key[] = {"msg2","msg2_alt"};
            return key[alt];
        }
    }
    return "unknown";
}
```

(**note:** the return type has been changed to `const char *` as you are returning the address of a *String Literal*. You will also want to validate `alt < 2` -- that is left to you)

Full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *response(int code, int alt) {
    switch (code)
    {
        case 1: {
            char *key[] = {"msg1","msg1_alt"};
            return key[alt];
        }
        case 2: {
            char *key[] = {"msg2","msg2_alt"};
            return key[alt];
        }
    }
    return "unknown";
}

int main (void) {
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j <= 1; j++)
            printf ("code: %d  alt: %d  response: %s\n", i, j, response(i, j));
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/switch_literal
code: 1  alt: 0  response: msg1
code: 1  alt: 1  response: msg1_alt
code: 2  alt: 0  response: msg2
code: 2  alt: 1  response: msg2_alt
```

Comment: Thanks David, it would be great if the redundancy of writting <return key[alt];> or declaring the the <key> variable could be avoided as in the other responses but looks like the only way to send the unknown message when the code is not known.

Comment: To finish the function, you can just condition the `switch()` on `if (0 <= alt && alt <= 1)`, e.g. `if (0 <= alt && alt <= 1) switch (code) { ... } return "unknown";` It doesn't matter whether you decalre one `key[]` and then switch or do it as I've done above. The compiler will likely optimize to the same code anyway `:)` And to fully tidy-up, make `const char *key[] = ...`